# Spring Boot REST API for moving toy robot in 5*5 grid

Tags: java, rest, spring

I have designed and coded REST APIs to move the toy robot in 5*5 grid. Please let me know any feedback on improvements, etc
Complete Code here:

https://github.com/pkkht/RobotRESTApp

```
package com.robotposition.controller;

import com.robotposition.model.RobotPositionCommands;
import com.robotposition.model.RobotPosition;
import com.robotposition.service.IRobotPositionService;
import jakarta.validation.Valid;
import jakarta.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

/**
 * @author Hari
 * REST API endpoints implemented for supported HTTP methods
 */
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/robotposition")
public class RobotPositionRestController {

    @Autowired
    IRobotPositionService robotPositionService;

    @PostMapping("/createRobotPosition")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createRobotPosition(@Valid @RequestBody @NotNull RobotPosition robotPosition) throws Exception {
        RobotPosition newRobotPosition = robotPositionService.createRobotPosition(robotPosition);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newRobotPosition, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<RobotPosition> getRobotPosition(@PathVariable @NotNull @Valid Integer id) throws Exception{
            Optional<RobotPosition> robotPosition = robotPositionService.findRobotPositionById(id);

            if (!robotPosition.isPresent()) {
                return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.ok(robotPosition.get());
            }
        }



    @GetMapping("/report")
    public ResponseEntity<List<RobotPosition>> getAllRobotPositions() {
        List<RobotPosition> robotPositions= robotPositionService.findAllRobotPositions();

        if (robotPositions.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(robotPositions);
        }
    }

    @PutMapping("/updateRobotPosition")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateRobotPosition(@Valid @RequestBody @NotNull RobotPositionCommands robotPositionCommands) throws Exception{
        if (!robotPositionService.findRobotPositionById(robotPositionCommands.getRobotPositionId()).isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        RobotPosition updatedRobotPosition = robotPositionService.updateRobotPosition(robotPositionCommands);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedRobotPosition, HttpStatus.OK);
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity deleteRobotPosition(@PathVariable @NotNull Integer id) throws Exception {
        if (!robotPositionService.findRobotPositionById(id).isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        robotPositionService.deleteRobotPositionById(id);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why doesn't updateRobotPosition have the ID in the request path? Does it update multiple robots? Naming doesn't indicate that. I expect this question to be closed as there is not enough context for review. A link to an (ever changing) git repository is not an excuse to not include all relevant code.

Comment: There are more than 10 classes. I don't think it is going to be very readable if I copy/paste them here. I am the owner of the repository and I don't expect it change.

Comment: Re. update method - it updates one robot's position.  The id is within the RobotPositionCommands object.

Comment: you should not alter your code/your question after it has been published... instead create a follow up story, where you show how your code evolved - see

Comment: i am still curious, none of your endpoints describes a **movement** - just some positions that can be set or updated... (i don't get that concept with `RobotPositionCommands`)

Comment: To be honest, if all of your classes are similar in size to this one then posting all of them would not make this question especially messy. As long as you preface each class with the file name it is readable. Unlike stack overflow we want to see as much code as possible.

Answer (score 2):

**Note:** i only review that part of your code that is posted in your question, i do not post issues on the code of your repository

### rest endpoint naming conventions

I would simplify these endpoints

```
- GET    /api/robotpositions/        (get all)
- GET    /api/robotpositions/{id}    (get one)
- POST   /api/robotpositions/
- UPDATE /api/robotpositions/{id} 
- DELETE /api/robotpositions/{id}
```

which would be totally comprehensible (try to follow [best naming practices](https://restfulapi.net/resource-naming/), especially see chapter 2.4) - did you also notice the plural on the resources?

### bad practice: using entity for dto

even though there is some discussion about that topic i strongly support the view of Cassio Mazzochi Molin - he wrote a very [clear article](https://cassiomolin.com/2016/03/23/why-you-should-use-dtos-in-your-rest-api/) about the benefits of separating these concerns

on the other hand: maybe your service is so small that you don't have to care about that (yet).

### minor issue 1 - empty lists are valid

an empty list is a valid result, so

```
- GET    /api/robotposition/        (get all)
```

will always return `200` - even though the result would be `[]` (in case you are using json) - this would give the client a a chance to see that there are currently no positions stored...

### minor issue 2 - exception handling

some of your methods throw exception, it is not clear why they do so...

- do you expect something that might happen (maybe in your Service?) then handle it properly
- do you just expect that anything can go wrong? that would be a runtime excpetion and that doesn't need to be proclaimed (additional: the spring boot framework handles all other exceptions for you and returns a 500 internal error)

### minor issue 3 - hungarian notation

its outdated and olfashioned - we do it no longer ;-)

its simply (without trailing **I**):

```
public interface RobotPositionService {
   //...
}
```

### minor issue 4 - unrequired java doc

> REST API endpoints implemented for supported HTTP methods

is totally reduntand since this is what the class is supposed to do ;-)
this is just a minor minor issue

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful.

Comment: i hope other user add more answers so i can learn from their point of view :-)

Comment: the more the merrier!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, lets' take these 1-at-a-time. Think of this exactly like a chessboard. Your robots must follow physical laws and they have rules of movement. You need to enforce those

```java
  @PostMapping("/createRobotPosition")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> createRobotPosition(@Valid @RequestBody @NotNull RobotPosition robotPosition) throws Exception {
        RobotPosition newRobotPosition = robotPositionService.createRobotPosition(robotPosition);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(newRobotPosition, HttpStatus.CREATED);
    }
```

First, one does not create a position. It's just illogical. The Robot `starts` somewhere (`{0,0}`). So, you are updating state and, in this case, it's not possible to have partial state update. The robot is either at `{1,0}` or it is not. So, `PATCH` and `POST` make no sense. The only thing you should really have is `PUT` (Maybe `DELETE` depending on your goals).

In addition, `REST` is `STATE TRANSFER` - using verbs on the url `createRobotPosition` is an antipattern.

In addition, you need to account for any number of robots:

So, Ideally, you're resource would be

`PUT /robot/{id}` where in you PUT the `position`. Or alternatively (or both):
`PUT /location/{x}/{y}/` and put the `ROBOT` at this position.

If you look at spring [HATEOS](https://spring.io/projects/spring-hateoas#samples) you'll see that these relationships are represented as hyperlinks, with their own media types. Both are valid since a robot relates to a position, and a position to a robot

There are other things to take into account, both in terms of error handling as well as your implementation.

```java
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<RobotPosition> getRobotPosition(@PathVariable @NotNull @Valid Integer id) throws Exception{
            Optional<RobotPosition> robotPosition = robotPositionService.findRobotPositionById(id);

            if (!robotPosition.isPresent()) {
                return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
            } else {
                return ResponseEntity.ok(robotPosition.get());
            }
        }
```

You have 2 ways you could simplify this code:

1. Recognizing the second `return` is superflous. If the original condition is true, then you return and the `else` is pointless. You can literally delete it (keep the secondary `return`).
2. You're using an `Optional` which has a built in `map` and `error`. And, you can use this to your advantage to eliminate the branch entirely by either:

```java
return robotService.findRobotPositionById(id)
    .map(RobotPosition::get)
    .orElse(ResponseEntity.notFound().build());
```

Optional has a built in `else`

or, you can actually throw an exception when not found, and let the Spring exception mapper generate the 404 (I'm not a fan of exception as they can really slow the app down with stack unwinding).

```java
return robotService.findRobotPositionById(id)
    .map(RobotPosition::get)
    .orElseThrow(ResourceNotFoundException::new)
```

Next one

```java
    @GetMapping("/report")
    public ResponseEntity<List<RobotPosition>> getAllRobotPositions() {
        List<RobotPosition> robotPositions= robotPositionService.findAllRobotPositions();

        if (robotPositions.isEmpty()) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(robotPositions);
        }
    }
```

See my previous comments about `return/else/Option` you can apply this here. But, `/robotpositions/report` is back to this anti-pattern of using a verb in the `URL`. In addition, it also doesn't capture the relationship between `robot` and `position` there isn't a resource called `robotposition` robots and positions relate to each other `1<->1`

So, this `URL` should be `GET /robots/` and then `.map(Robot::position)` or,
`GET /positions` and then `.map(Position::getRobot)`

In this below `update`, you should remove the redundant `RobotPosition` - with it, your URL would be `robotpositions/updateRobotPosition` - it's already a sub "resource" of `robotposition`.

remember to use `Optional` effectively as before. This code you're writing follow the old "check for null" pattern, which `Optional` is explicitly meant to address! You also need to check to see if another robot is at that position already and return `409 conflict`. The URL should be `PUT /positions/{id}` and `PUT` the robot there.

```java
    @PutMapping("/updateRobotPosition")
    public ResponseEntity<Object> updateRobotPosition(@Valid @RequestBody @NotNull RobotPositionCommands robotPositionCommands) throws Exception{
        if (!robotPositionService.findRobotPositionById(robotPositionCommands.getRobotPositionId()).isPresent()) {
            return ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
        }
        RobotPosition updatedRobotPosition = robotPositionService.updateRobotPosition(robotPositionCommands);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(updatedRobotPosition, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

DELETE doesn't make a whole lot of sense, but maybe. You can move the robot back to (`{0,0}`), but not without going everywhere in between. Ultimately your API really needs to model your problem space accurately. And, your validation probably should also insist that the id is not negative.

```java
    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity deleteRobotPosition(@PathVariable @NotNull Integer
```